# Python beautifulsoup 4 selecting a class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to make a tool to automate sneaker purchase. And I am trying to check availability of sneakers online. I am new to programming and this is my first project. Thank you.

```
def CheckStock(url, model):
  url = "http://www.adidas.com/us/pureboost-ltd-shoes/S80701.html?pr=product_rr&slot=3"
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
  html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
  Sizes = page.select('.size-dropdown-block')
  Sizes[0].getText()
```

I know that the page is being selected because I use the command page.title.string and It shows the right title. I am getting the following error when attepmtng to execute Sizes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#146>", line 1, in <module>
    x[0].getText()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The function works for me, requests 2.13.0, bs4 4.5.3. What is `x`?

Comment: Sizes[0].getText(). Sorry, Ignore the x just another instance of me testing out multiple code.

Comment: Please show us all relevant code. How do you initialize `x`? What exactly causes the error?

Comment: That is my code, I was using Python shell. I execute with  Sizes[0].getText()   x is just Sizes. Im not sure what causes the error, sorry new to python and programming

Answer (score 0):

Sizes is blue(it might be a function/methods use a different name for now) 
Check if the (.size-dropdown-block) exists in the source code.
CTRL+U (most browsers) or right click > View page source.
It might be javascript generated. IF it is, you'll have to use Selenium or another other automated browser.